Spring: check if annotation is used but bean is not present
I have some homemade annotation (let us call it @A) that can be used on RequestMappings to work with some OncePerRequestFilter (called MyFilter here).
I have made an autoconfiguration to conditionally create the MyFilter bean, and I now wish to perform the following check: if @A is used on at least one of my request mappings, throw an error if no instance of MyFilter is available.
In trying so, I have tried:

using Jakarta validation with a method inside the autoconfiguration, with and without @Validated/@Valid on the method and/or the autoconfiguration:
@AssertTrue(message = "Annotation A may not be used, no instance of MyFilter was provided")
private boolean isFilterAvailableIfAnnotationIsUsed(RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping, Optional<MyFilter> myFilter) {
  if (myFilter.isEmpty()) {
    for (HandlerMethod handlerMethod : requestMappingHandlerMapping.getHandlerMethods().values()) {
      if (handlerMethod.hasMethodAnnotation(A.class)) {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }

  return true;
}


looking into @PostConstruct, but it does not take beans as arguments
checking out BeanPostProcessor, but I am not sure I could use it that way

Now, the only idea I have left is to create a dummy bean that depends on RequestMappingHandlerMapping and Optional<MyFilter>, and which goal is just to throw an exception if the conditions are satisfied.
Is there a clean way of performing something like this?
